# DJANGO JQUERY-file-upload added file not shown in the template list

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use JQUERY-file-upload plugin to upload multiple files, after I added the container and file field, and try to upload, I can select multiple files, but the select files not be shown in the template table list.Below you may find the details:
The input and table as below in the html template:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
```

added the JS library and CSS as below:

```
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.ui.widget.js" %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.iframe-transport.js" %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.fileupload.js" %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js" %}" ></script>
<link href="{% static "css/jquery.fileupload.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static "css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

with below JS, I can select multiple files, but the selected files didn't show in the template table:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    filesContainer: $('table.files'),
    uploadTemplateId: null,
    downloadTemplateId: null,
    replaceFileInput:false,
    uploadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
                '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                '<div class="error"></div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><p class="size"></p>' +
                '<div class="progress"></div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                (!index && !o.options.autoUpload ?
                    '<button class="start" disabled>Start</button>' : '') +
                (!index ? '<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>' : '') +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
                row.find('.error').text(file.error);
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
        });
        return rows;
    },
    downloadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
                '<td><span class="preview"></span></td>' +
                '<td><p class="name"></p>' +
                (file.error ? '<div class="error"></div>' : '') +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><span class="size"></span></td>' +
                '<td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>' +
                '</tr>');
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
                row.find('.name').text(file.name);
                row.find('.error').text(file.error);
            } else {
                row.find('.name').append($('<a></a>').text(file.name));
                if (file.thumbnailUrl) {
                    row.find('.preview').append(
                        $('<a></a>').append(
                            $('<img>').prop('src', file.thumbnailUrl)
                        )
                    );
                }
                row.find('a')
                    .attr('data-gallery', '')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                row.find('button.delete')
                    .attr('data-type', file.delete_type)
                    .attr('data-url', file.delete_url);
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
        });
        return rows;
    }
});
```

Any idea on what's wrong on my code? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!